# if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ is exists and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ does not exists, then $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x))$ doesn't exists

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ is exists and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ does not
>   exists, then $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x))$ doesn't exists

Proof;

If we show that if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x))$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to c} fg(x)$ exists, we can prove the theorem.

So let assume $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x))$ exists, then 
$$(\forall \epsilon_1 > 0)(\exists \delta_1 > 0 : 0 < |x-c| \leq \delta_1 \rightarrow |f(x)-L_1| < \epsilon_1)$$
and
$$(\forall \epsilon_2 > 0)(\exists \delta_2 > 0 : 0 < |x-c| \leq \delta_2 \rightarrow |f(x)+g(x)-L_2| < \epsilon_2)$$

So if we choose $\delta_3 \leq min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$, the above conditions will be satisfied  for some $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, respectively.In other words,
$$-\epsilon_1 < L_1 -f(x) < \epsilon_1$$
$$-\epsilon_2 < f(x) + g(x) - L_2 < \epsilon_2$$

If we add 2 inequality and choose $\epsilon_3=\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ and $L_3 = L_2 - L_1$, we get

$$|g(x)-L_3| < \epsilon_3$$
, which is satisfied for all $\delta_3> 0$, so the theorem is proved.

---

Is there any mistake in the proof ? or do you have any advice about the construction of the proof or how I expressed while giving the proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use quantifiers properly. In particular, to prove that a function has a limit, you must pick *any* $\epsilon>0$ and prove the existence of *some* $\delta>0$ such that etc. Anyway, your approach can be made totally rigorous in a minute.

Your problem is essentially solved by the algebraic rules for computing limits. Indeed, if $f+g$ hconverges to some finite limit, and $f$ converges to a finite limit, then $(f+g)-f$ converges to the difference of the two limits. Hence $g$ has a limit. If you want, you can mimick the proof of this result and compare it with your "proof".

Comment: Can you spend 1 minute and make its rigorous version ?

Comment: Because as far as I know, in order to check something for **any** $\epsilon$, I have to use quantifier in order to make a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Leth You should, for instance, fix a number $\sigma>0$. Then you choose $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ in such a way that $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2 < \sigma$. Now your work is good, since there is no ambiguity between *some* and *every* in the various steps.

Comment: By the way, just a quick question, in the definitions, could I have said just $\epsilon$ for both $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, since they represent the same elements in the same set ?

Comment: Yes, you would have ended up with $2\epsilon$. But this is ok ;-)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. A shorter proof reads as follows:

Assumme that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x))$ exists.

Since $g=f+g-f$ it follws that $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ exists.

Comment: Is this the contra positive statement with respect to the theorem?